# Error in render: "TypeError: this.items.filter is not a function"

Tags: vue.js

Часть кода:

```
data () {
    return {
      items: [],
      chosen_vector_data: []
    }
},
computed: {
  filteredNotChosenVectors () {
    return this.items.filter((obj) => !this.chosen_vector_data.includes(obj))
  }
}
```

filteredNotChosenVectors эта функция  выводит ошибку  Error in render: "TypeError: this.items.filter is not a function". Не могу понять почему

Comment: Как в последующем коде вы модифицируете переменную `items`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const values = Object.values(obj);
```

мне помогло добавление вышеуказанной строчки